# AIML Condition Issue

Tags: conditional-statements, bots, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml

I'm trying to make this code work. It should work, since this was given to me by my teacher, however, it doesn't and I'm not sure why. It seems that, even though I seem to have the condition correct, it won't perform the actions under the condition for the "NO LO SE" value. Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml version="2.0">

<!-- Reglas paises, las modificaremos con LEARN -->

<category>
    <pattern>Cual es la capital de <set>pais</set></pattern>
    <template>La capital de <star/> es <map name="capital"><star/></map>.</template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>Cual es la capital de *</pattern>
    <template>No lo se</template>
</category>

<!-- Regla 17 de aprendizaje -->

<category>
<pattern>la capital de * es *</pattern>
<template>
    <think>
    <set var="cap"><srai>CUAL ES LA CAPITAL DE <star/></srai></set>
    </think>
    <condition var="cap">
        <li value="NO LO SE">
        <learn>
            <category>
            <pattern>CUAL ES LA CAPITAL DE <eval><star/></eval></pattern>
            <template>
                La capital de <eval><star/></eval> es <eval><star index="2"/></eval>
            </template>
            </category>
        </learn>
        Recordare que la capital de <star/> es <star index="2"/>
        </li>
        <li>
        Ya lo sabia.
        </li>
    </condition>
</template>
</category>

<!-- Fin paises -->

</aiml>
```

Comment: What intepreter are you using? Not all of them support the learn tag. You can check the condition is being activated by changing the learn part to some text like, "TEST" and seeing if it displays the word TEST.

Comment: I'm using program AB. Conditions seem to be working fine in other examples I've made. But I don't know why it won't work on this one. I tried adding "TEST" below the condition, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: It works fine for me in Program AB. Try putting another category in the AIML to see if your file is being accessed okay. What input are you saying to your bot and what reply does it give? Do you have any other AIML files that are overriding this one?